# How to recalculate only the active workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a vba macro to recalculate the active workbook.

I have tried to used those functions but without results :

- Application.CalculateFull (it recalculates all the workbook opened so
  it takes a lot of times)
- Something like that :

  ```
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  ActiveSheet.Calculate
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  ```
- Also this :

  ```
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      sh.Calculate
  Next sh
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the sheets in the ActiveWorkbook and calculate each one based on the sheet index:

```
Sub CalculateWorkbook()

Dim wb as Workbook
Dim i as Integer
Dim sheetCount as Integer

set wb = ActiveWorkbook
sheetCount = wb.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 to sheetCount
    wb.Sheets(i).Calculate
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: As far As I Know its quite similar to the last solution I gave. But you can browse all your workbook's sheet without any counter and by using a simple `For wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets `

Comment: @Dorian I was writing this while you were writing your edit... I'll leave this here for potential future visitors

Comment: No worries just wanted to be sure that it was the same. Kindest regards